# Repository for published data from medical studies

Tags: medical, drugs

Is there a repository for data from medical studies, in particular clinical drug tests? I am looking for data at the patient/mouse level, optimally from larger studies (exceeding 1000 individuals)

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple, but for me they don't have the level of data granularity to do the analysis I would like. It depends on the detail you need ...

- [clinicaltrials.gov](https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/about-site/results)
- [Consort](http://www.consort-statement.org/) - This is high level of analysis I believe.
- [Oncology Trials](http://theoncologist.alphamedpress.org/cgi/collection/clinical-trial-results)

Comment: Thank you. Indeed I am also looking at patient-level data.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried looking into Open Knowledge International?

https://discuss.okfn.org/c/projects/open-trials

They seem to have a discussion board on clinical trial archives as well as a database on drugs.